# Custom Social Sharing: shareUrl passing to URL but not actually sharing the shareURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter, social-networking

I have five custom share icons for Facebook, Twitter, Google Plus, Pinterest and Email. For each, on click, I would like them to share the current URL. The problem is that, while the shareURL is getting passed to the window URL (such as: https://twitter.com/share?url=shareURL), this shareURL is NOT getting passed into the dialogue box for each social medium. So even thought it appears in the browser URL box, the individual social users aren't actually sharing anything. The dialogue box appears empty.

In my example above, shareURL = thisURL in my script below. Here is a sample of my script:

```
function share_twitter(thisURL){
    window.open("https://twitter.com/share?url=" + encodeURIComponent(thisURL));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    thisURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;

    $(".twitter").click(function(){
        share_twitter(thisURL);

});
```

My hunch is that this has to do with global variables and the document ready function. Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

the arguments is not complete to redirect command, need variable %(cmd) to finish it up..
ex: https://twitter.com/share?url=%{url} , & make sure it has right url path check. try...